# What are the new nested scrolling APIs for Android-L?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm unable to find this info at https://developer.android.com/preview/api-overview.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

They did not draw much attention to this great new feature.  I've been toying with it, and I think I've figured it out.  All you have to do is is set

`android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"`

in the nested (child) scrollable view, assuming you have one somewhere inside another.  This causes the child view to scroll to completion, and then allow its parent to consume the rest of the scroll.  I found that I liked the opposite behavior better - parent gets scroll priority, then child follows - so I overrode the `onNestedScroll` method in ScrollView as follows:

```
@Override
public void onNestedScroll(View target, int dxConsumed, int dyConsumed, int dxUnconsumed, int dyUnconsumed) {
    //swap dyConsumed and dyUnconsumed
    super.onNestedScroll(target, dxConsumed, dyUnconsumed, dxUnconsumed, dyConsumed);
}
```

You should use this new ScrollView subclass for the outer (parent) ScrollView.

Comment: The correct way to do this is by consuming the scroll in onNestedPreScroll

Comment: Hey, How to start the nest scroll from the parent to the child?

Comment: right, but it is not the ScrollView that enable this, but other support widget such as the support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the [guyIntrepid's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25436990/2818583), be sure to add **onStartNestedScroll** to your custom ScrollView or ViewPager and **return true**.

```
@Override
public boolean onStartNestedScroll(View child, View target, int nestedScrollAxes){
   return true;
}
```

Comment: onStartNestedScroll() is now deprecated

Answer (score -2):

```
***Intento, hacer dos gridviews móviles(horizontal y verticalmente), dentro de un scrollview mas grande, pero al fijar el objetivo en los gridviews, solo me deja moverlos horizontalmente.***





<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/scv">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/tt">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center">


        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:backgroundTint="#50000000"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:id="@+id/NumeroPresupuesto"
            android:hint="Nº  presupuesto"
            android:textColorHint="#000000"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="#50000000"
            android:textColor="#F6D405"
            android:id="@+id/FechaPresupuesto"
            android:text="FECHA"/>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Importe Total:"/>
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#30000000"
                android:textColor="#F6D405"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/borrar_firma"
                android:text="0,00€"/>


        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/ln">



        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/hsv"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:measureAllChildren="false"
            android:scrollbars="none" >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >


                <GridView
                    android:id="@+id/Rejilla"
                    android:layout_width="1000dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#10000000"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
                    android:columnWidth="100dp"
                    android:numColumns="6"
                    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                    android:verticalSpacing="1dp">

                </GridView>
            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/ln1">

        <View
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:background="#000000" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Tarifa de Colaborador"/>

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/hsv1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:fillViewport="true" >
            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true">
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/innerLay1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >


                <GridView
                    android:id="@+id/Rejilla1"
                    android:layout_width="1000dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#10000000"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
                    android:columnWidth="100dp"
                    android:numColumns="6"
                    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                    android:verticalSpacing="1dp"

                </GridView>
            </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </HorizontalScrollView>

        <View
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:background="#000000" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="5pt">



        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:gravity="center">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:backgroundTint="#50000000"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:id="@+id/Codigo"
                android:hint="Unidad"
                android:textColorHint="#000000"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:backgroundTint="#50000000"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:id="@+id/Unidad"
                android:hint="Código"
                android:textColorHint="#000000"/>


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:gravity="center">


            <EditText
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:backgroundTint="#50000000"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:id="@+id/Medicion"
                android:hint="Medicion"
                android:textColorHint="#000000"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:backgroundTint="#50000000"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:id="@+id/PrecioPresupuestos"
                android:hint="Precio"
                android:textColorHint="#000000"/>


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:gravity="center">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:backgroundTint="#50000000"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:id="@+id/Importe"
                android:hint="Importe"
                android:textColorHint="#000000"/>

            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/CajaIVA">
            </Spinner>


        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
    <View
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="#000000" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:lines="5"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:gravity="top|left"
        tools:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:hint="Descripción"
        android:backgroundTint="#88000000"
        android:id="@+id/editText2" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:gravity="center">


        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="#000000"
            android:textColor="#F6D405"
            android:id="@+id/NuevoRegistro"
            android:alpha="0.4"

            android:text="Nuevo Registro"/>
        />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="#000000"
            android:textColor="#F6D405"
            android:id="@+id/EliminarRegistro"
            android:alpha="0.4"
            android:text="Eliminar Registro"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="#000000"
            android:textColor="#F6D405"
            android:id="@+id/GrabarRegistro"
            android:alpha="0.4"
            android:text="Grabar Registro"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>


</ScrollView>
```